# Как сравнить 2 числа и вывести совпадение?

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить 2 четырехзначных числа с четырехзначным числом(цифры все разные ) и вывести(в console) количество совпадений  например 1234 с 4321 (4 совпадения) , 1245 с 1234(3 совпадения). Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Цикл в цикле. Внешний цикл - берем цифры из первого числа, во внутреннем цикле - сравниваем с цифрами второго числа и считаем количество совпадений. Код напишите, а мы подправим ежели что )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

отличная задачка из codewars

```js
console.log(findSimilar(1234, 4321));
console.log(findSimilar(1111, 3333));
console.log(findSimilar(null, null));

function findSimilar(n1, n2) {
  var s1 = n1 ? n1.toString() : '';
  var s2 = n2 ? n2.toString() : '';
  var count = 0;
  for (var i1 = 0; i1 < s1.length; i1++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < s2.length; i2++) {
      if (s1[i1] == s2[i2])
        count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже нашел только здесь https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/48769-sravnenie-ehlementov-massivov.html . С codewars конечно короче)

Answer (score 5):

Предложу еще такой вариант:

```js
const foo = (number, pattern) =>
  number
   .toString()
   .split('')
   .reduce((res, num) => (pattern.toString().includes(num) ? res + 1 : res), 0)

console.log(foo(1234, 4321))
console.log(foo(1235, 1234))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно и так:

```js
function getDigitMatches(num1, num2) {
  const digits1 = [...`${num1}`];
  const digits2 = [...`${num2}`];
  return digits1.filter(digit1 => digits2.includes(digit1)).length;
}
```